# Finding similar images via tags

Tags: image, search, tags

## tl;dr

Fundamentally I'm looking for reasonable ways to ***implement*** a similarity rank among tag groups, where a tag group is 2 to 9 tags. Similar to ranking the similarity of 2 to 9 word sentences where the vocabulary is 200,000 words, except word order doesn't matter.

---

I have a collection of tagged images and I want to implement a couple of search functions:

1. Similar images
2. Similar but different images

where the similarity is based solely on the tags.

Finding identically tagged images isn't that hard, but after that I'm at a bit of a loss as to the best way to proceed. We have a hundreds of thousands of tags and no metadata on them, so we don't know that "Outlook" is related to "Microsoft" or "Windows" or "Email" and therefore cannot appreciate the difference in relatedness of an image tagged "Microsoft,Excel,Bar Graph" to an image tagged "Excel,Spreadsheet" versus one tagged "Visio,Bar Graph".

For "Similar images" we'd want to match "Microsoft,Excel,Bar Graph" to "Visio,Bar Graph" while for "Similar but different images" we'd want to match "Microsoft,Excel,Bar Graph" to "Excel,Spreadsheet".

My best guess at the moment is to treat the tags like text and throw them into [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). On the other hand, maybe a different kind of database, like Neo4j, would be the way to go.

Any suggestions on how to take a few steps forward? I'm not expecting a full solution, but suggestions for a general approach would be appreciated.

Extra Credit:

To make things more difficult, when tags are assigned to images, they are designated as "primary" or "secondary" and of course we want to take that into account.

Comment: IMHO this is a valid question. Why was this voted down thrice?

Comment: Can you clarify what cases you had in mind for "similiar images" vs "similiar but different images"? Aside from that I think the problem is clear.

Comment: "Similar" image is red car is similar to other red cars. "Similar but different" is red car to blue car but NOT to red car.

Answer (score 5):

## Update

Let's repeat the problem.

- The input data consists of sets of tags = set of strings (and pointers to the associated image resources)
- The strings are just character sequences, there is no additional semantic information available
- However there is a weighting of strings into 'primary' (higher weight) and 'secondary' (lower weight)

This means that the search has to rely solely on some similarity measure of sets (and strings).

Examples for such measures are:

- [Jaccard Similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index)
- [Dice Similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient)
- [Tverski Similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tversky_index)
- [Cosine Similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity)

This paper from 2010: [A weighted tag similarity measure based on a collaborative weight model](https://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/%7Entandon/papers/CIKM_new.pdf) applies several of those (and others) on the tag problem and shows how to include weighting. That should be helpful, IMHO.

Another (simpler) application can be seen in this paper from 2013: [Using of Jaccard Coefficient for Keywords Similarity](http://www.iaeng.org/publication/IMECS2013/IMECS2013_pp380-384.pdf).

### About the examples from the question

> For `"Similar images"` we'd want to match `"Microsoft, Excel, Bar Graph"` to `"Visio, Bar Graph"`

It would have some similarity due to that one tag (`"Bar Graph"`) is common to both sets of tags.

> while for `"Similar but different images"` we'd want to match `"Microsoft, Excel, Bar Graph"` to `"Excel, Spreadsheet"`.

Again one tag in common (`"Excel"`). But how should the system know that `"Visio"` is more similiar to the set `"Microsoft, Excel, Bar Graph"` than `"Spreadsheet"`?
That would require semantic information. I don't see how to solve this otherwise.

## Old Part

I found not much which would help you with your chosen approach (you restricted it quite a bit), except for a discussion of various metrics in the 2009 paper below.

But I would like to keep the steps of my little searching on this topic online here, because it puts your problem into context.

### Where others go

The research community seems to go in these directions:

- using the additional information about the users who provided the tags (*folksonomies*, *social tagging*)
- making use of semantic meta data (*ontologies*, *semantic similarity*)
- making use of visual image content (*content-based visual information retrieval*)

### Folksonomnies, Social Tagging

See this paper from 2009: [Evaluating Similarity Measures for Emergent Semantics of Social Tagging](http://www2009.org/proceedings/pdf/p641.pdf).

Instead of the traditional approach to define similarity by comparing the graphical data of the images

```
I = { (x, y, colour) }
```

by some measure (*content-based image retrieval*, *query by image content*, *content-based-visual information retrieval*), those authors use information (*harvest semantics*) from the tags, like you intend.

Their basic model consists of user assigned tags for a resource, comparing tuples of a so-called [folksonomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folksonomy)

```
F = { (user, resource, tag) }
```

which can be scaled down to your case of (resource, tag) tuples by different approaches to aggregate over the users resulting in different similarity measures.

### Semantic Similarity

Interesting is the use of [semantic similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_similarity), e.g. Jiang-Conrad, but alas, you have no semantic meta data (*ontology* e.g.) for your tags, which leaves you sticking to the similarity of the string representation of the words.

Again this paper [The Use of Ontologies for Improving Image Retrieval and Annotation](http://kmi.open.ac.uk/publications/pdf/kmi-08-08.pdf) from 2008 favours the use of ontologies, but I think it gives a nice discussion of the various approaches.

> *Folksonomies, social tagging systems that relies on the idea of the
> wisdom of the people. One representative example of this is Flickr.
> com. This approach overcomes the so much time consuming of
> manual annotation but the inconsistency in tag use can difficult the
> search through the entire collection of data.*

### Combination with Content-Based Visual Information Retrieval

Both papers above cite this paper [Augmenting Navigation for Collaborative Tagging with Emergent Semantics](http://iswc2006.semanticweb.org/items/Aurnhammer2006ve.pdf) from 2006.

> *However, using tags alone for searching and browsing databases clearly has
> its limitations. First, people make mistakes while tagging, such as spelling mistakes,
> or accidental tagging with the wrong tag. Second, there is no solution to
> cope with homonymy, i.e. to distinguish different meanings of a word. Third,
> synonymy or different languages can only be handled by tagging data explicitly
> with all terms.*

These authors combine *social tagging* with the initially mentioned *content-based image retrieval*.

Yet another link: [collaborative tagging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Models_of_collaborative_tagging).

Comment: Thanks. To simplify a bit, I'm totally not interested in doing anything with the image data itself at this point, because I want to reuse this for other content types. The tags are curated (drawn from a library), so we don't have to worry about inconsistent spellings, and can ignore homonymy problems. Fundamentally I'm looking for reasonable ways to implement a similarity rank among tag groups, where a tag group is 2 to 9 tags. Similar to ranking the similarity of 2 to 9 word sentences, except word order doesn't matter.

Comment: A practical introduction with the example code given in Python is Tony Segaran's book [Collective Intelligence](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529321.do), published by O'Reilly, where chapter 2 deals with recommendations and similarity. Exercise 2 is a tag recommendation problem.

Comment: A similarity metric for sets is the Jaccard similarity. See Haralambos Marmanis's and Dmitry Babenko's book [Algorithms of the Intelligent Web](http://www.manning.com/marmanis/), chapter 3. Their exposition of recommendation systems comes with Java code examples.

Comment: This [2012 paper by Anna Wilbik and James M. Keller](http://eldertech.missouri.edu/files/Papers/WilbikA/A%20distancemetricforaspaceoflinguisticsummaries.pdf) shows the [Jaccard metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) in action. They combine it with [fuzzy logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic) sets.

Comment: For the last part of your question: give higher weights to the more important tags, see [weight function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight_function)

Comment: This does not answer the question at all (and I think you know that), and it does not help me much, but I gave you the bounty because you did bring a lot of tangentially relevant information together to show other ways to tackle the bigger problem. I appreciate your effort.

Comment: I updated the answer. Please try and comment if it had any use.